# I am not able to dockerize the Corda spring boot server

Tags: spring-boot, corda

I am planning to run the **Corda nodes and the spring boot server** in a **docker container**. I have used the **dockerform** task to create the **docker-compose** file which is running the nodes perfectly.

I have created a **Dockerfile** to create **an image of the spring boot server** and build the **image** with the **docker build** command. I have used that image in the **docker-compose** file to run all the **containers in a bridge network**.

But the spring boot container is not able to connect to the Corda node.

**Caused by: net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.**

Comment: Please can you post your docker compose file and the node.conf of the node the spring boot server is trying to connect to.

Comment: Can you add them to the question please so they are readable. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue is solved. There was some issue with the host and port name. Now it's working.